# Tensorflow sort changes values in output list to 0 when the tensor datatype is tf.float32, but not tf.float64

Tags: python, tensorflow

Actions speak louder than words so here is the MWE:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n=17
a = tf.random.uniform(shape=[n], dtype=tf.float32)
print(a)
print(tf.sort(a))
```

When n<=16 it sorts the values just fine, but when n>16 it sorts the list and then turns the values at position 16 and higher to have value = -0. Example output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[0.41191268 0.48915362 0.65293264 0.6125376  0.00088847 0.03644979
 0.13768506 0.528106   0.27231824 0.4003389  0.5799836  0.83420205
 0.06494105 0.39109504 0.8135816  0.153288   0.07945895], shape=(17,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.00088847  0.03644979  0.06494105  0.07945895  0.13768506  0.153288
  0.27231824  0.39109504  0.4003389   0.41191268  0.48915362  0.528106
  0.5799836   0.6125376   0.65293264  0.8135816  -0.        ], shape=(17,), dtype=float32)
```

But when I make the dtype tf.float64 there is no problem for seemingly arbitrary n:

```
tf.Tensor(
[0.91347295 0.60086058 0.0271204  0.83564393 0.49664206 0.96215479
 0.60472639 0.64395121 0.58394402 0.93489432 0.50379539 0.14087138
 0.51662724 0.29758834 0.5657154  0.08638131 0.47912787], shape=(17,), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(
[0.0271204  0.08638131 0.14087138 0.29758834 0.47912787 0.49664206
 0.50379539 0.51662724 0.5657154  0.58394402 0.60086058 0.60472639
 0.64395121 0.83564393 0.91347295 0.93489432 0.96215479], shape=(17,), dtype=float64)
```

Not sure if this is a bug or expected behavior. It does not depend on eager execution. I was noticing issues when using the [tensorflowprobability percentile function](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile) where it was giving me -0.0 as the value, so I made my own percentile function and observed the same issue (which I suspect is due to this underlying issue with tf.sort). Numpy sorting works fine regardless of the data type, but I was trying to keep things within tensorflow.

Any reason why this might be happening or should I make a bug report?

**Hardware:** I am on an M1 Macbook Air using tensorflow 2.5.0

Comment: `tf.Tensor(
[0.0681721  0.17121959 0.20562828 0.21233249 0.22893572 0.35400736
 0.386518   0.45473194 0.51600516 0.5697123  0.6125848  0.70403075
 0.8660822  0.87743056 0.90173876 0.9186306  0.9941944 ], shape=(17,), dtype=float32)` I don't see that. 2.4.3 / Intel Mac

Comment: Interesting, thank you for testing. I suspect it might be an issue with the M1 version then.

Comment: I took the liberty of posting a [report](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51820). If it is a bug they will need some more details which you can provide.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug appears on M1 Macs with the Tensorflow Metal plugin. It only affects float32 and only occurs if the GPU is used. It occurs in conjunction with bothe tf 2.5.0 and 2.6.0: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51499
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689299?login=true

Answer (score 0):

I also checked the same with `tensorflow==2.5.0` as you mentioned and did not notice any issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Output:

```
2.5.0
```

and then

```
import tensorflow as tf

n=17
a = tf.random.uniform(shape=[n], dtype=tf.float32)
print(a)
print(tf.sort(a))
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[0.7946081  0.84397626 0.04671419 0.276353   0.8124876  0.66761124
 0.21016991 0.28140187 0.22393394 0.20382321 0.667526   0.1714747
 0.9672215  0.17870915 0.9914366  0.32059753 0.5422765 ], shape=(17,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[0.04671419 0.1714747  0.17870915 0.20382321 0.21016991 0.22393394
 0.276353   0.28140187 0.32059753 0.5422765  0.667526   0.66761124
 0.7946081  0.8124876  0.84397626 0.9672215  0.9914366 ], shape=(17,), dtype=float32)
```

with n>16:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n=18
a = tf.random.uniform(shape=[n], dtype=tf.float32)
print(a)
print(tf.sort(a))
```

Output:

```
    tf.Tensor(
[0.1922586  0.6136733  0.7517139  0.3762852  0.52895963 0.7804493
 0.9869323  0.08194113 0.3963052  0.6049119  0.9553219  0.18031311
 0.58210933 0.92059183 0.4442644  0.91004515 0.4451145  0.8300687 ], shape=(18,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[0.08194113 0.18031311 0.1922586  0.3762852  0.3963052  0.4442644
 0.4451145  0.52895963 0.58210933 0.6049119  0.6136733  0.7517139
 0.7804493  0.8300687  0.91004515 0.92059183 0.9553219  0.9869323 ], shape=(18,), dtype=float32)
```

Would you mind checking it back again and let us know if the issue still persists?